# How can I see all recently updated posts I'm associated with?

Tags: support

In the top left it says StackExchange, and I can see updates there with the little red circle whenever I have an answer that someone posts a comment for.  The problem is, as soon as I hover over that menu, the items are cleared, and I only get the first comment.

Where can I see all of this in a non-disappearing format so I can sequentially tackle all of these comments/new answers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the responses tab of the user page, as seen here:

[image: Free hand circles = auto up votes?]

The URL for this is as follows:

> https://stackoverflow.com/users/userId/?tab=responses

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the screenshot!